# EXCEL - Sum visible rows based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I´m going to paste a piece of a table that I need to handle the sale´s team for their everyday use. I have the following table:

[image]

If I use `SUBTOTAL` the result of adding "Total" column is 41,728 but the result I´m really looking for is 35,772 which is the one without duplicating data.

I can pull the trick with `=SUMPRODUCT(Tabla11[Total]/COUNTIF(Tabla11[Total],Tabla11[Total]))` but this sums everything, visible and non-visible rows.

I also can use `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET([ColB],ROW([ColB])-ROW(B2),,1)),[ColB]),[ColB]),[ColB]))` but it works only on one column, when WHAT I´m looking for is to avoid duplicity in **AREA COLUMN**, not on just on the working column as two different areas can have the same Total and thats perfectly ok.

That's what I´m dealing with now and I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: on the frequency, try changing all the `ColB` to the `Area` column **EXCEPT** the last one.

Comment: It would be the second one at the final no? It gives N/A

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Validation to avoid duplicate entries.

1. Select the cells or column that you want only unique values
2. Click `Data > Data Validation > Data Validation`
3. In the Data Validation dialog box Click the `Settings` tab.
4. Under the Allow drop down list, choose `Custom`
5. Enter this formula: `=COUNTIF($E:$E,E1)<2` where E is the column, E1 is the first cell of the column. 
   (You can use table column names instead of letters)
6. Click OK button

From now on, when you enter duplicate value it will stop an pop a warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Can u add a helper column? Assuming you have the table in column A and B, you can create a column in column C and type =COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,B2) in C2 then drag down. This shows how many duplicates exist above that line. Then use =SUMIFS(B:B,C:C,1).

P.S. this way, if you have any duplicates in the record (meaning area AND total have to be same), it will be ignored when summing. However, if there're records with same area but different total, it will still add.